# Swift How to fix Failed to set user defined inspected property on Please

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have problem with storyboard. I installed this: https://github.com/okmr-d/DOFavoriteButton and putted all effects in a Button correctly but now the storyboard have a lots of error in console and it makes app really slow. How can I fix that? Thank you!

**ERRORS**:

```
> 2015-10-08 19:33:01.629 AppName [45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOn) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8a23a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOn.
2015-10-08 19:33:01.630 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOff) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8a23a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOff.
2015-10-08 19:33:01.630 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (duration) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8a23a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key duration.
2015-10-08 19:33:01.938 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOn) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8afbb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOn.
2015-10-08 19:33:01.938 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOff) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8afbb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOff.
2015-10-08 19:33:01.938 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (duration) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8afbb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key duration.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.104 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOn) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8c3a40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOn.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.104 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOff) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8c3a40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOff.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.104 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (duration) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbcec8c3a40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key duration.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.257 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOn) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbceacae5c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOn.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.257 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOff) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbceacae5c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOff.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.257 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (duration) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbceacae5c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key duration.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.553 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOn) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbceadd34a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOn.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.553 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (imageColorOff) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbceadd34a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageColorOff.
2015-10-08 19:33:02.553 AppName[45857:6557884] Failed to set (duration) user defined inspected property on (UIButton): [<UIButton 0x7fbceadd34a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key duration.
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I saw that another button ( with class UIButton ) as same key value of DOFavorite class button. I deleted them and now works!

Comment: Please fix spelling/etc and add more information on the cause and fix so that the answer can be more helpful to others with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

As the selected answer is not exactly detailed I will leave this here for anyone with a similar problem.

I was having a similar problem, namely " Failed to set (selectedLineColor) user defined inspected property on (UITextField): [<UITextField 0x7faa0502dc00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selectedLineColor. "

The problem was for one of my UITextFields I initially set its class to SkyFloatingLabelTextField, and set some customs settings in the attributes inspector.   When I removed the class, the textfield still kept the custom settings, which was causing the error.

The settings were set in the identity inspector, under 'User Defined Runtime Attributes'.

I deleted the key in the box and the errors went away.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case by mistake module is not assign below the class. So, i have assign module and all works perfect.

Without Module Assign (Reason for Error) :-

[image]

**With Module Assign. (Solved issue) :-**

[image]